# Wildfly 15.0.1 Final: The controller is not available at localhost:9990

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I am trying to use Wildfly/JBoss to deploy a war of a program I made, but I keep receiving the following errors when I try to connect:

```
[disconnected /] connect 127.0.0.1:9990
The controller is not available at 127.0.0.1:9990: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect
 to remote+http://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection failed: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://127.0.0.1:9990
. The connection failed: Connection refused: no further information

[disconnected /] connect localhost:9990
The controller is not available at localhost:9990: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect
 to remote+http://localhost:9990. The connection failed: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:9990
. The connection failed: Connection refused: no further information

[disconnected /] connect localhost:9991
The controller is not available at localhost:9991: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect
 to remote+http://localhost:9991. The connection failed: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:9991
. The connection failed: Connection refused: no further information

[disconnected /] connect localhost:10000
The controller is not available at localhost:10000: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connec
t to remote+http://localhost:10000. The connection failed: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:10
000. The connection failed: Connection refused: no further information

[disconnected /] connect 127.0.0.1:9999
The controller is not available at 127.0.0.1:9999: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect
 to remoting://127.0.0.1:9999. The connection failed: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remoting://127.0.0.1:9999. The
connection failed: Connection refused: no further information

[disconnected /] connect 127.0.0.1:10000
The controller is not available at 127.0.0.1:10000: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connec
t to remote+http://127.0.0.1:10000. The connection failed: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://127.0.0.1:10
000. The connection failed: Connection refused: no further information

[disconnected /]
```

What I did were the following steps

1)Went to the Wildfly site

2)Downloaded the latest version of the standalone

3)Unpacked from the archive

4)Run on Windows the file jboss-cli.bat by double clicking on it

5)Typed what you can see above (and before that I also typed only "connect", without anything else. Still didn't work, same error for localhost:9990)

I must specify this is a clean download with no configuration changed, no file deleted, nothing modified at all. Not even the war was deployed. I also tried to add a rule to the Windows firewall to unlock the port 9990, still the same error. On port 9990 nothing is listening, I already checked in cmd. And I also restarted my PC before trying the connect commands, so nothing would be opened by me on that port.

I have the latest versions of JDK and JRE installed on my PC if that helps.

What is going on with this error, I am really lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I fixed the problem, and the solution was pretty straightforward. I forgot to open standalone.sh so wildfly can run, this being the reason jboss didn't connect.

Comment: LOL. Me too. Honest mistake. I really thought wildfly was already running.